# Custom prompt prints twice in PowerShell Core 6.0 on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, powershell, powershell-core

I have a custom PowerShell prompt function in my $PROFILE and it works fine on Windows for PS 5.1 and PS Core 6.0, but not for PS Core 6.0 on Ubuntu 17.04.

On Ubuntu prompt gets duplicated:
[image: duplicated prompt]

To make things more interesting, when I start typing, cursor moves and command text appears where I'd expect it to be if output was not duplicated:
[image: cursor in expected place]
Command will also print output on top of duplicated prompt output.

Output of `$PSVersionTable`:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                             
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                             
PSVersion                      6.0.0                                                                                                                                                                                             
PSEdition                      Core                                                                                                                                                                                              
GitCommitId                    v6.0.0                                                                                                                                                                                            
OS                             Linux 4.10.0-40-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 9 14:49:09 UTC 2017                                                                                                                                
Platform                       Unix                                                                                                                                                                                              
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                                                                                                                           
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                                                                                                                               
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1                                                                                                                                                                                           
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

Function that generated prompt:

```
function global:prompt {
    $realLASTEXITCODE = $LASTEXITCODE

    Write-Host
    Write-Host (Get-Date -Format:'o') -ForegroundColor:DarkGray
    Write-Host "PS " -NoNewline -ForegroundColor:Green
    Write-Host $pwd.ProviderPath -NoNewline
    # Write-VcsStatus
    Write-Host

    $global:LASTEXITCODE = $realLASTEXITCODE
    return "> "
}
```

I'm new to Linux and my search on what could have caused this weird behaviour are so far fruitless. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a bug in the version of PSReadLine that ships with Core.  Here's the [issue](https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine/issues/468)

You can install the prerelease version of 2.0.

```
Install-Module PSReadLine -RequiredVersion 2.0.0-beta1 -AllowPrerelease -Force
```

If you get a error about `-AllowPrerelease` you need to update `PowerShellGet` as well.

```
Install-Module PowerShellGet -RequiredVersion 1.6.0 -Force
```